# Why fn:substring-after Xquery function could not be used inside ML TDE

Tags: xquery, marklogic, tde, marklogic-10

In my ML db, we have documents with distributor code like 'DIST:5012' (DIST:XXXX) XXXX is a four-digit number.

currently, in my TDE, the below code works well.

[image]

However instead of concat all the raw distributor codes, I want to simply concat the number part only. I used the fn:substring-after XQuery function.  However, it won't work. It won't show that distributorCode column in the SQL View anymore. (Below code does not work.)

[image: ![enter image description here]

What is wrong? How to fix that?

Both fn:substring-after and fn:string-join is in TDE Dialect page.
https://docs.marklogic.com/9.0/guide/app-dev/TDE#id_99178

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`substring-after()` expects a single string as input, not a sequence of strings.

To demonstrate, this will not work:

```
let $dist := ("DIST:5012", "DIST:5013")
return substring-after($dist, "DIST:")
```

This will:

```
for $dist in ("DIST:5012", "DIST:5013")
return substring-after($dist, "DIST:")
```

I need to double check what XPath expressions will work in a DTE, you might be able to change it to apply the `substring-after()` function in the last step:

```
fn:string-join( distributors/distributor/urn/substring-after(., 'DIST:'), ';')
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I need to always remember to check the difference between a single value and a sequence of values when working with Xquery. ; )